# How to help search engines to find all the pages on my website

Tags: seo, google-search

I currently program a website which gives information about food products.

The way the website works is that there's a search engine -> the users search for the product they want to know something about -> the website shows all the products that they may want to see, and every product has his own page with all the information about it.

So my question is: how search engines, like google, will be able to find all the product pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search engines use many different ways to find new pages. Most commonly their [web crawlers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler) follow (external as well as internal) hyperlinks.

While a typical informational website links to all available pages in its site-wide navigation (so web crawlers can reach all pages by following internal links), other websites don’t necessarily link to all their pages (maybe because you can only reach them via forms, or because it doesn’t make sense for them to provide all links, etc.).

To allow discovery/crawling of new pages of these sites, too, they can provide a [site map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site_map). This is essentially just a page linking to all existing pages, but often with structured metadata that can help search engines.

**So just make sure that all your pages are linked somehow.** Either via "natural" internal links on your site, or by providing a sitemap (ideally following the [sitemaps.org protocol](http://www.sitemaps.org/)), or both.

For questions about SEO advice (which is off-topic here on SO), see our sister site https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Please add sitemap in your site for google crawling all pages easily and indexing properly.

also add xml sitemap

your website need SEO process.