# Does site seo benefit from having a sitemap on top of using microdata?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seo, sitemap, schema.org, microdata

I have recently been doing a lot of reading on SEO with HTML5 (I am a Rails web developer), and have been doing a lot of work with microdata as I have seen that the Schema.org format is the preferred format of Google.

What I am wondering, is if somebody can explain to me the importance of also including a sitemap?

From what I understand, the crawlers just go through all the links on a page from wherever they come to your site, and then are able to gather all the data they need from well written microdata tags.

So what is the additional benefit of including a sitemap, and is it really worthwhile? It is possible that I am misunderstanding the purpose of a sitemap or the functionality of search engine crawlers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A consumer can only read the Microdata if it found the document which contains it.

A sitemap is *one* way (of many ways) that allows consumers to find the document. A common other way is to [follow hyperlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26433672/1591669) (from plain HTML, no Microdata needed), but there may be sites that don’t link to every document, so consumers would not find these documents that way.

(If it’s worthwhile, e.g. if there’s a SEO benefit, depends on the consumer. A consumer can be a search engine bot, any other bot, a tool, a browser extension, etc.)

Comment: (And note that asking if something is good/bad for SEO is off-topic here on Stack Overflow. It’s on-topic on [webmasters.se].)