# Bing.com indexes URLs i've never submitted

Tags: seo, search-engine, bing

Sometimes, before launching new web projects, i put the site / app under a subdomain like new.domain.com or beta.domain.com.

These URLs are only meant for my clients. So they don't get submitted at search engines and there aren't any public links to them.

However, I noticed in a few occasions, these subdomains get indexed by Bing anyway. How is this possible ?

Does Bing crawl generic subdomain names like new, old, archive, beta, ... ?
Or do URLs sent in mails, get scraped in Office 365 (which my clients use) and get indexed ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Comment: [How do search engines obtain unlinked pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41395462/1591669)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible the user has installed a toolbar from that search engine.

The best way to prevent from this, is adding no-index tag for all pages in sub domain and even you can block using robot.txt.